# selecting distinct value in linq mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

i am binding the below data to a drop down but am not able to get disctinct value. Please help. Find the code snippet below

```
var SalesOrgTypes = (from s in tblSales
                         orderby s.SalesOrg ascending
                         select new DropDownItem
                         {
                             Value = s.SalesOrg,
                             Text = s.SalesOrg + " - " + s.SalesOrgDesc
                         }).Distinct();
```

Comment: You haven't said what's actually happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct()` is using the definied `Equals(object obj)` method of the `DropDownItem`. You have to define a proper `IEqualityComparer` and give it to the `Distinct(IEqualityComparer<T>)` method to tell `Distinct` not to use the native `Equals(object obj)` method, but your own equalization.

```
class DropDownItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DropDownItem>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<DropDownItem> Member

    public bool Equals(DropDownItem x, DropDownItem y)
    {
        return
            x == null || y == null 
            ? false
            : x.Value == y.Value && x.Text == y.Text; 
        //Or whatever properties you want to be equal
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DropDownItem obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
            return
                obj.Value.GetHashCode() + obj.Text.GetHashCode();
        else
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can give this to the `Distinct` method

```
var SalesOrgTypes = (from s in tblSales
                         orderby s.SalesOrg ascending
                         select new DropDownItem
                         {
                             Value = s.SalesOrg,
                             Text = s.SalesOrg + " - " + s.SalesOrgDesc
                         }).Distinct(new DropDownItemEqualityComparer());
```